# Sockets between Android app and Java application on the same phone

Tags: java, android, linux, sockets, ubuntu

This question is related to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39661583/android-linux-deploy-access-phone-sensors

I have a rooted samsung galaxy s3, I have installed ubuntu on the phone using linux deploy https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.meefik.linuxdeploy&hl=en_GB. I understand that this means that ubuntu runs in a 'chrooted' (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot) env and can not directly access files in the android part of the phone.

I want to try and set up communication between the two Os's so that I can call methods from the ubuntu os that access the phones features.

I thought I might be able to do this by writing a simple app on the android part that acts as a socket server. I would then have a simple client java program that runs in ubuntu that connects to that socket on the android app.

This is what I have so far:

The android MainActivity.java file:

```
package com.example.sam.myfirstapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void go(View view){
        try{
            ServerSocket serverSock = new ServerSocket(4242);

            while(true){
                Socket sock = serverSock.accept();
                PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
                String advice ="This is my sent message";
                writer.println(advice);
                writer.close();

            }
        } catch (IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The activity_main.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_start"
        android:onClick="go"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The java file running on ubuntu is:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class hello_world {

    public void go() {
     System.out.println("In go method");
     try{
     Socket s = new Socket("192.168.0.10", 4242);
     InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream());
     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
     String advice = reader.readLine();
     System.out.println(advice);
     reader.close();
     } catch(IOException ex) {
     ex.printStackTrace();
     }
    }



    public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("hello, world!");

    hello_world myhello =  new hello_world();
    myhello.go();
    }
}
```

Both the server and client seem to compile okay.
I run the app in android and click the button to initiate the server.
I then go to ubuntu and run the java program.

The java program gives a connection refused exception.

Is this method of communication between the os's possible? If so what is going wrong and how do I rectify it?

Comment: how can you be sure ip of client, 192.168.0.10 ? I would try, 127.0.0.1 and localhost

Comment: Yes I tried those first, but got connection refused. So I looked up the IP the phone was using on my router and tried that but still connection refused error.

Comment: Is the server working?

Comment: I think so.. I dont get any exceptions when I press the button

Comment: That doesn't mean your server code is running at the time you try to connect the client.

Answer (score 0):

Try running your server in a [Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).

Comment: Can you give an example? I have tried: 
`public void go(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, HelloIntentService.class);
        startService(intent);
        try {
            TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(2);
            stopService(intent);
        } catch(Exception ex){
            stopService(intent);
        }
    }` with ..

Comment: `public class HelloIntentService extends IntentService {
    public HelloIntentService() {
        super("HelloIntentService");
    }     @Override protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {try{
            ServerSocket serverSock = new ServerSocket(4242);while(true){Socket sock = serverSock.accept();PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());String advice ="message";
           writer.println(advice);
                writer.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}`

Comment: Can you connect to anything in the chroot environment?